# Javascript Sticky Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, drupal, frontend, navbar, sticky

So i am trying to write a very simple script, just a simple javascript file for a sticky nav bar. I'll put the code below, but I am having this weird issue where the whole page is blank when my _scroll code block is executed. error in console was "$links is undefined" but I'm fairly certain that isnt it. One person said that I may be trying to call links twice? but I dont see how. Using drupal 9 if that helps. Thanks!

````
import { FireComponent, FireHelpers } from '@base';

export class SidebarLinks extends FireComponent {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
  }

  get elements() {
    return {
      $links: this.$component.find('[data-links]'),
    }
  }

  _scroll() {
      if (window.scrollY == this.elements.$links) {
        $links.addClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
        }
      else {
        $links.removeClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
      }
  }

  init() {
    if (!this.componentExists) return;

    this._scroll();
  }
}```
````

Comment: Why don't you use `position: sticky` in css?

Comment: Where do you declare `$links`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski   get elements() {
    return {
      $links: this.$component.find('[data-links]'),
    }
  }

I thought this get elements method would declare the $links. as for the css its on its own css file

Comment: No, it won't. https://javascript.info/variables You have to declare variable to use it

Comment: @KonradLinkowski just so i am understanding correctly, you need to declare a variable that stores the value of $links, then use that above my if else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a getter, but you never use it.

Either use it or declare your `$links`

### Option 1

```
import { FireComponent, FireHelpers } from '@base';

export class SidebarLinks extends FireComponent {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
  }

  get elements() {
    return this.$component.find('[data-links]'),
  }

  _scroll() {
      if (window.scrollY == this.elements.$links) {
        this.elements.addClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
      }
      else {
        this.elements.removeClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
      }
  }

  init() {
    if (!this.componentExists) return;

    this._scroll();
  }
}
```

### Option 2

```
import { FireComponent, FireHelpers } from '@base';

export class SidebarLinks extends FireComponent {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
    this.$links = this.$component.find('[data-links]')
  }

  _scroll() {
      if (window.scrollY == this.elements.$links) {
        this.$links.addClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
      }
      else {
        this.$linkslements.removeClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
      }
  }

  init() {
    if (!this.componentExists) return;

    this._scroll();
  }
}
```

### Option 3

```
import { FireComponent, FireHelpers } from '@base';

export class SidebarLinks extends FireComponent {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id);
    this.
  }

  _scroll() {
      const $links = this.$component.find('[data-links]')
      if (window.scrollY == this.elements.$links) {
        $links.addClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
      }
      else {
        $linkslements.removeClass('sidebar-links__sticky');
      }
  }

  init() {
    if (!this.componentExists) return;

    this._scroll();
  }
}
```